# shortcut to a dynamic web page

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

“is it possible to generate a shortcut to a page,
For example: dynamic content on a web page contains 15documents and I want clicking on one of them to create a shortcut to it on my desktop”

Very short question I know
Thanks very much

Comment: You can't let a website make a shortcut on your desktop. If that is possible this would be a major leak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not.

1. The desktop is a platform-specific thing, Web APIs tend be cross-platform.
2. If there was such an API (even one with a confirmation dialog), you would see it on every Ad-Page.

Comment: thanks very much guys for the quick reply, I assumed so but I was just triple checking